# Composer reinstalls everything every time I create a new Laravel project - why?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm messing about with Laravel 4, which looks great.

However, every time I create a new project I have to wait 10 minutes while Composer downloads all the dependencies. Surely they needn't be downloaded more than once?

```
05:36:49 ~/projects$ composer create-project laravel/laravel myproject
Installing laravel/laravel (v4.0.5)
  - Installing laravel/laravel (v4.0.5)
    Loading from cache

Created project in myproject
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing doctrine/lexer (dev-master bc0e1f0)
    Cloning bc0e1f0cc285127a38c6c8ea88bc5dba2fd53e94

[.. installs for 10 minutes ... ]
```

Any way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the `--prefer-dist` switch to the command line. That should force Composer to download ready-made ZIPs with the required versions.

But do note that you have a dependency on "dev-master" for doctrine/lexer - these will usually only be resolved by cloning the GIT repository instead of always downloading the latest tip of that branch. Try to require a known version tag or version wildcard instead.